# How to send array using html form

Tags: arrays, forms, symfony, twig

so I need to send array to other page. I was tried to make it by form:

```
<form action="{{ path('_przepisy') }}" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name = "produkty" value = "{{ sniadanie }}">
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-success pull-right" value="Przepisy"/>
</form>
```

"sniadanie" is array, for example it works as: sniadanie[0]['ilosc']

On page "przepisy" I tried to use this code:

```
{% set produkty = app.request.get('produkty') %}
{{produkty[0]['iloscuser']}}
```

But it doesn't work. Somebody have idea how can I do this?

Comment: do you absolutely must need to use form to send the array value ? if not a must, you can use session. if u must use form, use a loop function to extract all the array value and put it in the "hidden input value"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not specific to Symfony2. Its basic HTML. You have to supply multiple input with appropriate name. You cannot sent an array value in a single input element!! Thats basic HTML!!

```
<form action="{{ path('_przepisy') }}" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name = "produkty[0][iloscuser]" value = "specific-value-from-sniadanie">
<input type="hidden" name = "produkty[1][iloscuser]" value = "specific-value-from-sniadanie">
<input type="hidden" name = "produkty[2][iloscuser]" value = "specific-value-from-sniadanie">
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-success pull-right" value="Przepisy"/>
</form>
```

But you can send a json string inside a single element.

```
<form action="{{ path('_przepisy') }}" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name = "produkty" value = "{{ sniadanie | serialize }}">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success pull-right" value="Przepisy"/>
</form>
```

Then in controller

```
$this->render("your view", [
    'produkty'  => json_decode($request->get('produkty'))
]);
```

And in the template

```
{{produkty[0]['iloscuser']}}
```

Comment: Thanks for help :) I decided to do it in other way, I just use now in controler:
return $this->render('MainBundle:Default:przepisy.html.twig', array(
     "sniadanie" => $sniadanie));
And works ok too :P