# POST a JavaScript array of Strings into Spring Boot/Thymeleaf form Object

Tags: javascript, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am using Spring Boot and Thymeleaf with some vanilla JavaScript. In my JavaScript, I have an array of strings as below:

```
var tags = ["ramen", "japanese"];
```

I want to use JavaScript to dynamically add/remove items in this array before it gets submitted to the backend. The user can add 0..* tags.

Data gets submitted to the backend only via HTML `<form>` submits. There is also a model attribute which captures these details from the HTML form into Spring called VenueForm.

```
<form id="tag-form" class="form" method="POST" th:object="${venueForm} th:action="/venue/tag">
```

VenueForm.java

```
public class VenueForm {
    private List<String> tags;
    private Object otherStuff;
    ...
    // Getters and Setters
}
```

VenueController.java

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/venue/tag")
public class VenueController {

    @PostMapping
    public String createVenue(@ModelAttribute VenueForm venueForm){
       List<String> tags = venueForm.getTags();
       System.out.printLn(tag);
       return "tags"
    }
}
```

How do I assign the JavaScript array `tags` to the Thymeleaf form List field `tags`?

Usually the input comes from `th:field="*{tags}"` in an input field but because its an array I am not sure how to achieve this. Any help would be much appreciated. Please note jQuery is not an option, only vanilla JS.

I have tried to stop the HTML form submit using JS, then assigning the input field using JS but that did not work.

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" th:onsubmit="submitForm(event)">
```

main.js

```
function submitForm(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    venueTagInput.value = JSON.stringify(tags);
    console.log("sumitting...");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This existing post has helped me figure this out ([Send Array using HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30288491/how-to-send-array-using-html-form))! Thymeleaf is just a templating engine on the server side, it renders into basic HTML. There is no need to do anything Thymeleaf specific to send an array of elements in the form. You have to follow the basic HTML way using the name attribute on an input field. You can use Javascript to create new DOM elements and making sure that for each element the index is incremented. No changes are needed on the controller side. Spring can work out that name="tags[0]" is tags.get(0);

```
<input type="text" class="form-control tag" id="1" name="tags[0]" value="">
```